# Appium precise scroll using TouchAction

Tags: java, android, scroll, appium

Appium 1.5.3, macOS Sierra, Android 5, Java

I would like to scroll down a listview for a certain number of pixels(-400). 
I am using this code:

```
TouchAction touchAction4 = new TouchAction(driver);
touchAction4.press(400, 800).moveTo(0,-400).waitAction(2000).release();
touchAction4.perform();
```

But it works like a fast scroll by finger about a few height of screen.
waitAction does not help.

Comment: Have you tried driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, duration). U can use the duration parameter  to slow down the scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using swipe method of the driver.

`driver.swipe(startX, startY, endX, endY, durationMilis)`